# pandoc 2.5 rejecting underscores (.tex to .md)

Tags: pandoc

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu installation from 18.04 to 20.04. This upgraded my `pandoc` to version 2.5. This brought some incompatibilities like `--smart` not being supported anymore, and one more that I haven't been able to fix.

I'm trying to convert .tex files to .md. Suddenly `pandoc` is choking on underscores that were just fine before:

```
Error at "source" (line 281, column 50):
unexpected _
We can set the initial value of \texttt{recursion_depth} to a sensible value such as 3, as discussed previously.
                                                 ^
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation saying that underscore handling has changed in recent versions. I thought that maybe I'm missing some extension for the input or output format, but I haven't found anything either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was a bug in 2.5 - upgrading to the latest version (2.14 at this time) made the error go away.